# how to resolve ambiguous situation between same named function and class?

Tags: c++, class, function, ambiguous

This code compiles without any issue if test is not called so I conclude that c++ allows to create class and function with the same name:

```
class test {};
void test() {}

int main() {
  test an_instance_of_test;
}
```

error is:

```
<stdin>: In function 'int main()':
<stdin>:5:8: error: expected ';' before 'an_instance_of_test'
<stdin>:5:27: warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function 'test' [-Waddress]
```

And I know that I should not create such unambiguity in the first place but nevertheless this may be experienced in someones else code and I'm asking if there is a way out of this without changing function or class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an elaborated type specifier:

```
class test an_instance_of_test;
```

As the standard says (§3.4.4):

> An *elaborated-type-specifier* (7.1.6.3) may be used to refer to a previously declared *class-name* or *enum-name* even though the name has been hidden by a non-type declaration.

The name lookup simply ignores any names of non-types:

> the identifier is looked up according to 3.4.1 but ignoring any non-type names that have been declared.